# Is there a way to increase the screenshot frequency of the RoboTest in Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am testing an application with the RoboTest on Firebase Test Lab and need to gather screenshots of as much of the application as possible. Everything seems to work just fine until about 30 minutes into the RoboTest and the screenshot frequency decreases from once every minute to about once every 5 minutes. I realize there is video but it's faster for me to just look through screenshots, especially when the RoboTest is over 30 minutes long.

Is there a way to maintain a certain screenshot frequency with the RoboTest? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Robo doesn't stop taking as many screenshots at a specific time, but the frequency of screenshots might decrease if Robo doesn't see a lot happening/changing on screen!

Unfortunately, there's no way to specify screenshot frequency.